# Multiple Field Properties and Text into Header Table in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, header, field, cell

I am able to update the header of a word doc with the required formatting with the following code:

```
    Dim myRange As Range
    With ActiveDocument
        Set myRange = .Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
        .Fields.Add Range:=myRange, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="STYLEREF  Title", PreserveFormatting:=True
        myRange.Collapse wdCollapseStart
        myRange.Text = ""
         myRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
           Set myRange = .Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
    myRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    myRange.InsertParagraphAfter
    myRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
myRange.Text = "Name: "
    myRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Fields.Add Range:=myRange, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="Name_1", PreserveFormatting:=True
myRange.Fields.Update
Set myRange = .Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
    myRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    myRange.InsertParagraphAfter
    myRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Fields.Add Range:=myRange, Type:=wdFieldDate, PreserveFormatting:=True
    myRange.Collapse wdCollapseStart
        myRange.Text = "Date: "
    myRange.Fields.Update
  myRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight

           Set myRange = .Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
    myRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    myRange.InsertParagraphAfter
    myRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
myRange.Text = "Page: "
    myRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
               .Fields.Add Range:=myRange, Type:=wdFieldPage, PreserveFormatting:=True
myRange.Fields.Update
    Set myRange = .Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
   myRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
myRange.Text = " of "
myRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
             .Fields.Add Range:=myRange, Type:=wdFieldNumPages, PreserveFormatting:=True
    myRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
             myRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
myRange.Fields.Update

End With
```

I am trying to place the Text and Field Codes from the above code into a table cell within the header section of the word doc using variations of the code below.

```
Dim MyRange As Range
With ActiveDocument
Set MyRange = ActiveDocument.Sections(1). _
Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary). _
Range.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Range
MyRange.Collapse wdCollapseStart
MyRange.Fields.Add Range:=MyRange, _
               Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
               Text:="STYLEREF  Title", _
                             PreserveFormatting:=True
MyRange.InsertParagraphAfter

Set MyRange = ActiveDocument.Sections(1). _
Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary). _
Range.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Range
MyRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
MyRange.Text = "Name: "
MyRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
MyRange.Fields.Add Range:=MyRange, _
               Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
               Text:="Name_1", _
                             PreserveFormatting:=True
Set MyRange = ActiveDocument.Sections(1). _
Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary). _
Range.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Range
MyRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
MyRange.Text = "Date: "
MyRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
MyRange.Fields.Add Range:=MyRange, _
               Type:=wdFieldDate, _
                             PreserveFormatting:=True
Set MyRange = ActiveDocument.Sections(1). _
Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary). _
Range.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Range
MyRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
MyRange.Text = "Page: "
MyRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
MyRange.Fields.Add Range:=MyRange, _
               Type:=wdFieldPage, _
                             PreserveFormatting:=True
MyRange.InsertParagraphAfter
Set MyRange = ActiveDocument.Sections(1). _
Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary). _
Range.Tables(1).Cell(1, 2).Range
MyRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
MyRange.Text = "Num Page: "
MyRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
MyRange.Fields.Add Range:=MyRange, _
               Type:=wdFieldNumPages, _
                             PreserveFormatting:=True
MyRange.InsertParagraphAfter
```

The error "This is not a Valid Action for End of Row" appears. It seems to be tied to the "wdCollapseEnd" command and I am unable to retain my desired formatting. Any ideas on how to retain the correct formatting while adding the required field properties with a cell?

Comment: The easiest way to insert complex structures such as tables, fields, and content controls into headers is to save them as building blocks/AutoText in the template and you can use your code to insert those. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#UsingVBABuildingBlock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One wonders why you're doing this in code instead of using a template with all the boilerplate content in-situ.

That said, your first code block could be reduced to something like:

```
Sub DemoA()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim sTb As Single
With ActiveDocument.Sections(1)
  sTb = .PageSetup.PageWidth - .PageSetup.RightMargin - .PageSetup.LeftMargin
  With .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
    .Text = vbNullString
    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    .Fields.Add Range:=.Characters.Last, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="STYLEREF Title", PreserveFormatting:=False
    .Characters.Last.Text = vbCr & "Name: "
    .Paragraphs.Last.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
    .Paragraphs.Last.Range.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Add Position:=sTb / 2, Alignment:=wdAlignTabCenter
    .Paragraphs.Last.Range.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Add Position:=sTb, Alignment:=wdAlignTabRight
    .Fields.Add Range:=.Characters.Last, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="Name_1", PreserveFormatting:=False
    .Characters.Last.Text = vbTab & "Date: "
    .Fields.Add Range:=.Characters.Last, Type:=wdFieldDate, PreserveFormatting:=False
    .Characters.Last.Text = vbTab & "Page: "
    .Fields.Add Range:=.Characters.Last, Type:=wdFieldPage, PreserveFormatting:=False
    .Characters.Last.Text = " of "
    .Fields.Add Range:=.Characters.Last, Type:=wdFieldNumPages, PreserveFormatting:=False
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

For which the table equivalent is:

```
Sub DemoB()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Tbl As Table, Rng As Range
With ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
  .Text = vbNullString
  Set Tbl = .Tables.Add(Range:=.Duplicate, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=3)
  Tbl.Rows(1).Cells.Merge
  Tbl.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
  Set Rng = Tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range
  Rng.End = Rng.End - 1
  Rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  .Fields.Add Range:=Rng, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="STYLEREF Title", PreserveFormatting:=False
  Set Rng = Tbl.Cell(2, 1).Range
  Rng.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
  Rng.Text = "Name: "
  Rng.End = Rng.End - 1
  Rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  .Fields.Add Range:=Rng, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="Name_1", PreserveFormatting:=False
  Set Rng = Tbl.Cell(2, 2).Range
  Rng.Text = "Date: "
  Rng.End = Rng.End - 1
  Rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  .Fields.Add Range:=Rng, Type:=wdFieldDate, PreserveFormatting:=False
  Set Rng = Tbl.Cell(2, 3).Range
  Rng.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
  Rng.Text = "Page: "
  Rng.End = Rng.End - 1
  Rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  .Fields.Add Range:=Rng, Type:=wdFieldPage, PreserveFormatting:=False
  Rng.End = Rng.Cells(1).Range.End - 1
  Rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Rng.Text = " of "
  Rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  .Fields.Add Range:=Rng, Type:=wdFieldNumPages, PreserveFormatting:=False
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

or, more simply:

```
Sub DemoC()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Sections(1)
  With .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
    .Text = vbNullString
    .Fields.Add Range:=.Characters.Last, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="STYLEREF Title", PreserveFormatting:=False
    .Characters.Last.Text = vbCr & "Name: "
    .Fields.Add Range:=.Characters.Last, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="Name_1", PreserveFormatting:=False
    .Characters.Last.Text = vbTab & "Date: "
    .Fields.Add Range:=.Characters.Last, Type:=wdFieldDate, PreserveFormatting:=False
    .Characters.Last.Text = vbTab & "Page: "
    .Fields.Add Range:=.Characters.Last, Type:=wdFieldPage, PreserveFormatting:=False
    .Characters.Last.Text = " of "
    .Fields.Add Range:=.Characters.Last, Type:=wdFieldNumPages, PreserveFormatting:=False
    .ConvertToTable Separator:=vbTab
    With .Tables(1)
      .Columns.DistributeWidth
      .Rows(1).Cells.Merge
      .Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
      .Cell(2, 1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
      .Cell(2, 3).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
    End With
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

For use with an existing table in the header:

```
Sub DemoD()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Tbl As Table, Rng As Range
With ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
  Set Tbl = .Tables(1)
  Set Rng = Tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range
  Rng.End = Rng.End - 1
  Rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  .Fields.Add Range:=Rng, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="STYLEREF Title", PreserveFormatting:=False
  Set Rng = Tbl.Cell(2, 1).Range
  Rng.Text = "Name: "
  Rng.End = Rng.End - 1
  Rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  .Fields.Add Range:=Rng, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:="Name_1", PreserveFormatting:=False
  Set Rng = Tbl.Cell(2, 2).Range
  Rng.Text = "Date: "
  Rng.End = Rng.End - 1
  Rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  .Fields.Add Range:=Rng, Type:=wdFieldDate, PreserveFormatting:=False
  Set Rng = Tbl.Cell(2, 3).Range
  Rng.Text = "Page: "
  Rng.End = Rng.End - 1
  Rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  .Fields.Add Range:=Rng, Type:=wdFieldPage, PreserveFormatting:=False
  Rng.End = Rng.Cells(1).Range.End - 1
  Rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Rng.Text = " of "
  Rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  .Fields.Add Range:=Rng, Type:=wdFieldNumPages, PreserveFormatting:=False
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! The above code works. I should have been clearer in my problem description. I need to have those fields inserted into an existing table within the header section. The second cell of the the first row.  I have reposted the question with the updated description  at the link below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74142545/field-properties-and-text-into-existing-table-within-header-in-word

Comment: @Nordberg - please close your new question. Editing the code in the answer to work with an existing table is a trivial task. Just replace `Set Tbl = .Tables.Add(Range:=.Duplicate, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=3)` with `Set Tbl = .Tables(1)`

Comment: @TimothyRylatt, I have made your suggested edits to Sub DemoB(), but when I run the new code (I've updated the reference cells as well) an error message is thrown at the set Tbl = .Tables(1) line. I message states that "The requested member of the collection does not exist."

Comment: @Nordberg - did you forget to remove the line that clears the header (`.Text = vbNullString`)?

Comment: I have made the following edits: 1) replaced 'Set Tbl = .Tables.Add(Range:=.Duplicate, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=3)' with 'Set Tbl = .Tables(1)' 2) Updated all cell references to (1,2). 3) Removed '.Text =vbNullString' The new error message that appears is "Object Variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: @Nordberg - on which line does the error occur?

Comment: It appears on the first occurrence of 'Set Rng = Tbl.Cell(1, 2).Range'

Comment: @Nordberg - Did you read through the code before you ran it? If you had you would realise that macropod's code merges the cells of the first row, so you don't have two cells in row 1. You should never run code unless you understand what each line does.

Comment: I failed to include that within my edits section. I removed the merge command as it removed info from the first cell in the row.

Comment: I have updated the answer with code to populate an existing table. All you need do is ensure the cell references are correct for the table you're using.